# Specific simplification of expression $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1 + \sum_{j=i+1}^n\frac{1}{m}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Can someone provide some guidance on the following simplification step in the summation below. I'm wondering how to convert what's on the left to what is on the right.

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1 + \sum_{j=i+1}^n\frac{1}{m}\right) = 1 + \frac{1}{nm} \sum_{i=1}^n(n-i).$$

My own attempt at simplification led me to the following:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1 + \sum_{j=i+1}^n\frac{1}{m}\right) &=
\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 1 + \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n \frac{1}{m} \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\left( n + \frac{n(n-1)}{2m}\right)\\
&=1 + \frac{n-1}{2m}.
\end{align*}$$

I believe my simplification is correct, but am not sure how to creatively simplify the sum to get the result listed prior. Ultimately, this simplification is necessary as further on in the simplification process key variables get subsituted into the  equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1 + \sum_{j=i+1}^n\frac{1}{m}\right)$$

There are n copies of the first term (1) and then it is averaged outside by dividing by $n$, so we would get a 1.

For the second term inside, for each $i$, we are getting $(n-i)$ copies of $\frac 1 m$, which means a total of $\sum _i (n-i)$ of it, and as before, it gets divided by $n$ outside, so we end up getting $ \frac{1}{nm} \sum_{i=1}^n(n-i)$.

Alternative way to show equivalence between what you have and what you want:

Start from what you want and simplify.

$ \frac{1}{nm} \sum_{i=1}^n(n-i)= \frac{1}{nm} (\sum_{i=1}^n n-\sum_{i=1}^ni)=\frac{1}{nm} (n^2-n(n+1)/2)$

Simplify and you are done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is great except I believe you meant to simplify $\sum_{i=1}^n i$ to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ instead of $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.